# How to get the scaling factor before it is reset to 1,1

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, vsto

I have a System.Windows.Forms.UserControl. Below I only show the relevant parts.

The InitializeComponent is automatically generated by Visual Studio and cannot be touched because
it is modified every time I touch the designer and compile it.

**MyTaskPane.Designer.cs**:

```
 partial class MyTaskPane
 {
    
        private System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost ElementHostFormControl;
        private MyWPFUserControl  MyWPFUserControl;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.ElementHostFormControl = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost();
            this.MyWPFUserControl = new MyWPFUserControl();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // ElementHostFormControl
            // 
            this.ElementHostFormControl.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.ElementHostFormControl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.ElementHostFormControl.Name = "ElementHostFormControl";
            this.ElementHostFormControl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 40);
            this.ElementHostFormControl.TabIndex = 0;
            this.ElementHostFormControl.Child = this.MyWPFUserControl;
            // 
            // MyTaskPane
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Controls.Add(this.ElementHostFormControl);
            this.Name = "MyTaskPane";
            //this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }
 }
```

And below the another partial class:

```
public partial class MyTaskPane: System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
{

        private System.Drawing.SizeF scaleFactor;

        public MyTaskPane()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Gets the scaling factor.
            // Do not perfom ResumeLayout before getting auto scale factor because
            // Unfortunatly, as soon as the scaling is applied, the AutoScaleFactor
            // is reset to 1, 1.
            this.scaleFactor = this.AutoScaleFactor;

            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        public System.Drawing.SizeF ScaleFactor
        {
            get
            {
                return this.scaleFactor;
            }
        }
}
```

As you can see above, I have a Winforms application and I embed on it a WPF UserControl using an ElementHost.

I need to get the scaling factor because I am using it later in my code to do some resize so I get it by calling the this.AutoScaleFactor after calling the InitializeComponent method within the constructor.

The call to this.AutoScaleFactor should be done before calling ResumeLayout(false), otherwise I am not getting the correct scaling factor because it is reset to 1,1 after execution of ResumeLayout(false). So I know that I cannot do that but I have commented the line this.ResumeLayout(false) at the end of the InitializeComponent method which it is not recommended since it is a method automatically generated by Visual Studio and all the changes done there will be lost if it is re-generated again, and I have moved this line to the constructor, after calling InitializeComponent method and after getting the scaling factor.

I do not know how to do it in another way. I need to get the autoscale factor. Some people say that the scaling factor could be obtained by calculating the scaling with the form's actual size as below:

```
  float scaleX = (float)this.Size.Width/ mDesignSize.Width;
  float scaleY = (float)this.Size.Height/ mDesignSize.Height;
```

but I don't know how to obtain those values to calculate it.

In theory with above formula I would have to obtain the same scaling factor value as I get when calling the this.AutoScaleFactor.

So how can I solve this? How to face this situation? I need to obtain the scaling factor. My workaround is working, but I don't like to touch an automatically generated method.

Comment: What's that for? The Form already performs this calculation on its own, comparing `CurrentAutoScaleDimensions` (run-time) with `AutoScaleDimensions` (design-time) and if these don't match, calls `PerformAutoScale()` -- If you host your UserControl in a WPF app, it should be designed Dpi-Aware, before it gets DpiAware (System-Aware) by proxy.

Comment: @Jimi Well rather than a winform app its is an VSTO Outlook Add-in and the MyTaskPane UserControl finally is embedded into and Outlook object (A custom task pane). Then for some reason this Outlook object is not resizing its height so then I get the Y-Scaling factor and do the resize by multiplying the height with the Y-scaling  factor. Having said that, I need to get the autoscaling factor, just by calling the this.AutoScaleFactor that is just what I am looking for. The problem is that if you call it after ResumeLayot then the scaling factor you obtain is reset to 1,1.

Comment: @Jimi This is the reason why then I comment the ResumeLayout line in the auto-generated code (within InitializeComponent) and instead I perform it just after doing the call to InitizalizeComponent from the constructor in the partial class and right after obtaining the scaling factor through this.AutoScaleFactor. So how can I get the correct scaling factor without having to comment that auto-generated line at the end of the method InitializeComponent?

Comment: @Jimi Right before executing ResumeLayout I have put a breakpoint and I observe that this.CurrentAutoScaleDimensions (12, 25) has a different value from this.AutoScaleDimensions (6, 13) so then may I understand/assume that ResumeLayout calls PerformAutoScale()? If so, Could I override the method PerformAutoScale and before performing its logic get the autoscale factor there through this.AutoScaleFactor?

Comment: Auto-scale if performed (if `AutoScaleMode` is not `AutoScaleMode.None`) when the Layout changes for different reasons. For example, each time the Font changes, or for the many reasons why `OnLayout()` is called, which of course includes the call to `ResumeLayout()`. When that method is called, it sets `AutoScaleDimensions = CurrentAutoScaleDimensions` -- You should scale to Dpi instead of Font and either make you UserControl DpiAware or disable automatic DpiAwareness when it becomes part of a WPF application (as Outlook).

Comment: @Jimi how can i ensure that the designer uses always 6F, 13F, so then when comparing them they will be the same and scaling factor would be 1,1 so then no problem i guess